# angular 6 build chunks names are weird and size is huge

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6, angular-cli-v6

I am using angular 6 and I preload all my components,
I have 8 components: `ScreensComponent`, `AccountComponent`, `DashboardComponent`, `FinderComponent`, `ListerComponent`, `MonitorComponent`, `AuthComponent`, `LoginComponent`

but the output is 11 files (not including the main.js and other files).

I am unable to understand why there are 11 chunks and their names are weird.
Also, most of the files are so huge and I cant seem to understand why everything weighs so much

```
chunk {8} account-account-module-ngfactory.3381d22a1e8d5db6b823.js (account-account-module-ngfactory) 70.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.29cb0c319e11420627c6.js (scripts) 876 kB  [rendered]
chunk {0} common.e58351c45cec4bb0f84d.js (common) 17.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {1} account-account-module-ngfactory~finder-finder-module-ngfactory~lister-lister-module-ngfactory.9fd06129611a0271f9ea.js (account-account-module-ngfactory~finder-finder-module-ngfactory~lister-lister-module-ngfactory) 26 kB  [rendered]
chunk {2} finder-finder-module-ngfactory~lister-lister-module-ngfactory~screens-screens-module-ngfactory.d512470383c55e2004b8.js (finder-finder-module-ngfactory~lister-lister-module-ngfactory~screens-screens-module-ngfactory) 68.2 kB  [rendered]
chunk {3} lister-lister-module-ngfactory~monitor-monitor-module-ngfactory.00e81bc0649f067026a6.js (lister-lister-module-ngfactory~monitor-monitor-module-ngfactory) 228 kB  [rendered]
chunk {4} monitor-monitor-module-ngfactory.145e0aaf56cca28ab92d.js (monitor-monitor-module-ngfactory) 238 kB  [rendered]
chunk {5} lister-lister-module-ngfactory.00baef5ecda629c1924b.js (lister-lister-module-ngfactory) 1.03 MB  [rendered]
chunk {6} finder-finder-module-ngfactory.0c67cb70a42e4e1248fd.js (finder-finder-module-ngfactory) 234 kB  [rendered]
chunk {7} dashboard-dashboard-module-ngfactory.0a194d0dd1e6b3d22216.js (dashboard-dashboard-module-ngfactory) 1.49 kB  [rendered]
chunk {9} login-login-module-ngfactory.3803a9fde37726d2fcb1.js (login-login-module-ngfactory) 97.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {10} screens-screens-module-ngfactory.517275ed05ee9a3474b9.js (screens-screens-module-ngfactory) 200 kB  [rendered]
chunk {11} auth-auth-module-ngfactory.9b8c7640150610ba12dc.js (auth-auth-module-ngfactory) 62 kB  [rendered]
chunk {12} runtime.b75eb3e8646a750ee46a.js (runtime) 2.68 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {13} styles.80497f4105b47590510a.css (styles) 80.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {14} polyfills.c428b26f0c9cd88ad9e2.js (polyfills) 64.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {15} main.bfa19806e0940a6dbd7e.js (main) 1.06 MB [initial] [rendered]
```

Comment: Having a similar issue in Angular 9, did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

It's the webpack compiler, which creates these files bij chunking all files and node_modules into some minified javascript files.

Answer (score 0):

These files are not for production but for development and debugging. If you build using `ng build --prod` you will get the actual files to be deployed.

Comment: Nope, the chunk-naming is still broken with `ng build --prod --namedChunks`:

https://imgur.com/gallery/aeW0bjK